# Good and bad reduction for twists of algebraic curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-curves, galois-theory, finite-fields

Suppose we have two curves $C/\mathbb{Q}$ and $C'/\mathbb{Q}$ which are twists of each other i.e. they are isomorphic over a field extension $K/\mathbb{Q}$.

Suppose that $C$ has good reduction at a prime $l$. Is it true that $C'$ has good reduction at $l$ if and only if $l$ is unramified in $K$? It seems to me that this should be the case (for example by looking at quadratic twists of elliptic curves) but I am not sure why it is true. Could someone provide a proof or a reference for a proof?

Comment: What is your definition of "the" field extension $K/\mathbb{Q}$?  There is a torsor for a group scheme over $\mathbb{Q}$ whose rational points give all such field extensions.  But there is no obvious reason that there should be a single "minimal" such field extension.  If you allow non-minimal $K$, then definitely you will not have an "if and only if" equivalence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $B$ be a Dedekind scheme with function field $K$. (Think of $B=\mathrm{Spec } \ \mathbb{Z}_{p}$ for simplicity, so that $K=\mathbb{Q}_p$.) Let $C$ be a smooth proper geometrically connected curve over $K$ of genus at least one with good reduction over $B$. Let $\mathcal{C}\to B$ be its (unique) smooth proper model.

Let $C'$ be a twist of $C$ over $K$. Let $L/K$ be a finite field extension such that $C'_L \cong C_L$ over $L$. One can use the theory of Neron models for curves due to Liu-Tong to prove the following (see https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.4822).

*Lemma.* Assume that the normalization  $B'$ of $B$ in $L$ is (finite flat) etale over $B$. Then $C'$ has a smooth proper model over $B$.

**Proof.** Let $\mathcal{C}'\to B$ be the Neron model of $C'$ over $B$. Since $B'\to B$ is finite etale, the basechange $\mathcal{C}'\times_B B'$ is the Neron model of $C'_L$ over $B'$. Since $C'_L\cong C_L$, we have that $C'_L$ has good reduction over $B'$. In particular, its Neron model is proper over $B'$. Thus, $\mathcal{C}' \times_B B'\to B'$ is proper (as it is the Neron model of $C'_L$ over $B'$). We conclude that $\mathcal{C}'\to B$ was already proper. In particular, $\mathcal{C}'\to B$ is a smooth proper model for $C'$ over $B$. QED

Concretely: when $K=\mathbb{Q}_p$ and $B=\mathrm{Spec} \ \mathbb{Z}_p$, if $C'$ is a twist of $C$ which has good reduction after passing to an unramified extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, then it must have already had good reduction over $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: Thank you @Ariyan! I just wanted to ask why $L/K$ being unramified implies that $B'$ is finite flat etale over $B$ and do you have a good reference for these notions?

Comment: @did you're welcome. By definition, by $L/K$ being unramified, I really just meant that the normalization of $B$ in $L$ is unramified. But the normalization $B'\to B$ is a finite surjective morphism and if it is unramified, then it is in fact etale (by normality of $B$). I  can highly recommend Liu's book on Arithmetic Geometry.

Comment: A bit more explanation: When we say that a field extension $K/\mathbb{Q}_p$ is unramified, we really mean that $\mathbb{Z}_p\subset O_K$ is unramified. But $O_K$ is the normalization (read: integral closure) of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ in $K$.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the case of an elliptic curve $A$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and a quadratic extension $K$ of $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $A_{\ast}$ be the Weil restriction of $A_{K}$. Then
$c(A_{\ast})=N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(c(A_{K}))d_{K/\mathbb{Q}}^{2}$. Here $c$ is the conductor and $d$ the discriminant. As $A_{\ast}$ is isogenous to the product of $A$ and its twist, and isogenies don't change conductors, I think this gives what your want. Reference: Milne, Invent. Math. 1972, Pptn.1.

The formula, in fact, holds for abelian varieties, so if a curve and its quadratic twist both have good reduction, then the quadratic field $K$ must be unramified.